How do I upload Nextjs 14 app to hostinger with the dynamic routes and pages working?
I have a nextjs 14 news app with a backend to upload news everyday. How do I upload the Nextjs app to hostinger to build the dynamic routes?
I tried building it and the out folder was created but it only built the static pages

You probably want to take a look at the supported features for static exports.

Next JS v14 with App Router cannot be deployed to Hostinger shared hosting, this can only be done using VPS.strong textThis limitation means that deploying a fully functional Next.js app with dynamic routes and server-side rendering features may not be feasible.
